# JSON won't save on scope AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, json

i have a problem with saving JSON on a scope, I have already a function saving a JSON into a scope and works perfectly but the second one won't save...

servicoLeituraPosts.php returns JSON with data
servicoLeituraComments.php returns JSON with data

both send JSON through URL correctly, and the first shows data on scope, but the second one doesn't and it's done exactly like the first one, so I don't understand what is going on.

1st one saves JSON into $scope.posts, it has data and i can print it
2nd one saves JSON into $scope.comments, if i print it, it is blank? Why? Thank you for help but I'm a beginner in AngularJS.

```
<script>
    var app = angular.module('postsApp', []);
    var interval;

    app.controller('postsCtrl', function($scope) {
        $scope.toggle = false;
        $scope.texto = [];
        $scope.comment = [];
        $scope.comment = "";
        $scope.comments = [];
        $scope.posts = [];
        $scope.texto = "";
        $scope.idPost = 0;
        $scope.showBox = function(p){

          p.toggle = !p.toggle;


          if(interval == 0){            
            interval = setInterval("angular.element($('#postsApp')).scope().servicoLeituraPosts()",1000);
          }else{
            clearInterval(interval);
            interval = 0;
          }

            $scope.servicoLeituraComments(p);

            console.log($scope.comments);
            console.log($scope.posts);

        };
        $scope.iniciaTimer = function(){
               interval = setInterval("angular.element($('#postsApp')).scope().servicoLeituraPosts()",1000);        
        };
        $scope.servicoLeituraPosts = function(){        
                $.getJSON(
                        "servicoLeituraPosts.php",
                        {

                        },
                        function(jsonData)
                        {
                            $scope.posts = jsonData;
                            $scope.$apply();
                        });
        };
        $scope.servicoLeituraComments = function(p){        
                $.getJSON(
                        "servicoLeituraComments.php",
                        {
                            "idPost": p.idPost
                        },
                        function(jsonData)
                        {
                            $scope.comments = jsonData;                        
                            $scope.$apply();
                        });

                        console.log($scope.comments);
        };
        $scope.addPost =  function(){                              
                $.post(
                    "addPostRest.php",
                    {
                        "texto" :  $scope.texto
                    },
                    function(dados)
                    {
                        $scope.texto = dados.indexOf("OK") >= 0 ? "" : "FALHOU";
                        $scope.$apply();
                   }
                );
        };
        $scope.addLike =  function(idPost){
                $.post(
                    "addLike.php",
                    {
                        "idPost" : $scope.idPost = idPost
                    },
                    function(dados)
                    {
                        $scope.texto = dados.indexOf("OK") >= 0 ? "" : "FALHOU";
                        $scope.$apply();
                    }
                );
            };
             $scope.addComment =  function(p){                              
                $.post(
                    "addComentarioRest.php",
                    {

                        "comment" : p.comment,
                        "idPost" : p.idPost
                    },
                    function(dados)
                    {
                        $scope.texto = dados.indexOf("OK") >= 0 ? "" : "FALHOU";
                        $scope.$apply();
                    }
                );
            };      

    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution, apparently there was a problem with the parameter recieved on POST which made the JSON invalid having no data

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are calling `console.log($scope.comments);` synchronously after calling `$.getJSON(...)`, rather than waiting for the `jsonData` to be returned. At this point the $scope is yet to be updated.

Try moving the `console.log` into the callback:

```
function(jsonData)
{
    $scope.comments = jsonData;                        
    $scope.$apply();

    console.log($scope.comments);
});
```